# How to search Object stored in HashMap

Tags: java, oop, hash

I have a Question on HashMaps.  How can I search and return object details  from HashMap

I declared the hashmap below

```
private  HashMap <String,Champions> AllChampions = new HashMap<String, Champions>();
```

Below I declared and added a an object to the Array, And which I want to search

```
Champions d = new Worrier("Elblond", 200, "Sword");

AllChampions.put(b.getName(), b);
```

How Can I search the Object stored in Hash Map. The code I used below doesn't work

```
private boolean isChampion(String name)
{
    return AllChampions.containsKey(name);
}


public String getChampion(String name)
{
    if (isChampion(name))
    {
        return AllChampions.get(name).toString();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: public Champions getChampion(String name){ return AllChampions.get(name); } this return the champion with the given name. Then you do whatever you want with the Champion object. for example Champions champ = getChampion("Elblond"); String weapon = champ.getWeapon(); //weapon is equals to "Sword"

Comment: What doesn't work? What behavior are you seeing, and what do you expect to see?

Comment: you create `d`. but you put `b`.then how you can get `d`?

Comment: what you mean by _doesn't work_ anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Your bug is here:

```
Champions d = new Worrier("Elblond", 200, "Sword");
AllChampions.put(b.getName(), b); // you are adding b, but declared d
```

Change it to:

```
AllChampions.put(d.getName(), d);
```

---

BTW, your `getChampion()` method adds little value: Just use `AllChampions.get(name)` directly.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion to ur last method.

```
public Champion getChampion(String name)
{
    if (AllChampions.containsKey(name))
    {
        return (Champion) AllChampions.get(name);
    }
    return null;
}
```